# Tuple.Create in F#

Tags: .net, f#, tuples, base-class-library

I noticed a quite weird behavior of the `System.Tuple.Create` method in F#. When looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it indicates that the return type is of `System.Tuple<T>`. However when using this method in F# all overloads except `Tuple.Create(T)` will return `'T1 * 'T2`. Obviously invoking the `Tuple<T>` constructor will return `Tuple<T>`. But I don't understand how the return type of the `Tuple.Create` is different in F#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tuple type of F# (a syntactic tuple) is compiled as `System.Tuple<..>`. So they are the same type at .NET level but for F# type system they are different types: the type of a syntactic tuple will not match the type of a `System.Tuple<..>` but their runtime type will be the same.

You can find a detailed description in the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf)

The example with `new System.Tuple<'t>()` does not return a syntactic tuple, probably because you are instantiating explicitly a specific type and you should get back exactly that.

Here are some tests:

```
let x = new System.Tuple<_,_>(2,3) // Creates a Tuple<int,int>
let y = System.Tuple.Create(2,3)   // Creates a syntactic tuple int * int

let areEqual = x.GetType() = y.GetType() // true

let f (x:System.Tuple<int,int>) = ()
let g (x:int * int) = ()

let a = f x
let b = g y

// but

let c = f y 
//error FS0001: The type 'int * int' is not compatible with the type 'Tuple<int,int>'

let d = g x
// error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type int * int but here has type Tuple<int,int>
```

So, at compile time they are different but at runtime they are the same. That's why when you use `.GetType()` you get the same result.

Comment: Interesting; while syntactic tuples are compatible with `System.Tuple` on interop, F# refuses to compile `System.Tuple<int, int>(1,1) = (1, 1)`. *I don't know how this could cause issues in practice, but it is a relevant point, so I deleted my answer in favor of this one.*

Comment: @Vandroiy If need be, you could use the Equals override: `System.Tuple<int, int>(1,1).Equals((1,1))`